# Pattern printing using java

Tags: java

can you guys help me with this pattern

size must be N X M. ( N is an odd natural number between 5 to 101, and M is 3 times N.)
The design should have 'WELCOME' written in the center.
The design pattern should only use  | , .  and - characters.

Example patterns are shown in image

[image: example patterns]Can

```
class DimondText{
 
 

   
  static void createPattern(int n, int m){
         int c=m/2;
          for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(i%2!=0 || i==1){
              for(int j=i;j<=c;j++){
                  System.out.print("- ");
 
             }
             for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                 System.out.print(". | .");
                 j+=1;
             }
             for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
                 System.out.print(". | .");                                                                                                            
                 j+=1;
             }
             for(int j=i;j<=c;j++){
                 System.out.print("- ");
             }
              System.out.print("\n");
         }
       }
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){                    
      System.out.print("- ");
         }
     System.out.print("\n");

     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
       if(i%2!=0){
        for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++){
            System.out.print("- ");
         }
         for(int j=i;j<c-i;j++){
            System.out.print(". | .");
            j+=1;
         }
        for(int j=i;j<c-i;j++){
            System.out.print(". | .");
            j+=1;
        }
         for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++){
             System.out.print("- ");
         }
         System.out.print("\n");       }
    }

   }

     public static void main(String[]arg){

         createPattern(7,21);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck? What is the output you're getting?

Comment: Your String literals contain spaces that do not appear in the sample images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void createPattern(int n){
    String word = "WELCOME";
    int m = n * 3, n2 = n / 2, w = (m - word.length()) / 2;
    for (int i = 0, h = n2 * 3, v = 1; i < n2; ++i, h -= 3, v += 2)
        System.out.println("-".repeat(h) + ".|.".repeat(v) + "-".repeat(h));
    System.out.println("-".repeat(w) + word + "-".repeat(w));
    for (int i = 0, h = 3, v = n2 * 2 - 1; i < n2; ++i, h += 3, v -= 2) 
        System.out.println("-".repeat(h) + ".|.".repeat(v) + "-".repeat(h));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createPattern(5);
    System.out.println();
    createPattern(7);
    System.out.println();
    createPattern(11);
}
```

output:

```
------.|.------
---.|..|..|.---
----WELCOME----
---.|..|..|.---
------.|.------

---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------

---------------.|.---------------
------------.|..|..|.------------
---------.|..|..|..|..|.---------
------.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|.---
-------------WELCOME-------------
---.|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.------
---------.|..|..|..|..|.---------
------------.|..|..|.------------
---------------.|.---------------
```

Comment: From requirement: "_N is an odd natural number between 5 to 101, and_ ***M is 3 times N***" Because of that, you should calculate _M_ instead of passing it as an input. Declare _M_ as local to the method and just pass _N_ to the _createPattern()_ method. For example, _createPattern(7)_.